# Parse Date from MM/DD/YYYY to a format MYSQL can work with

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Currently working with a MLS data dump in which all their dates are formatted in MM/DD/YYYY , Trying to get the min/max age

```
        MIN( DateDiff( NOW(), idx_common.list_date ))) AS listage_min,
        MAX( DateDiff( NOW(), idx_common.list_date ))) AS listage_max
```

Obviously this does not work because `idx_common.list_date` is in said format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert `idx_common.list_date`.

```
MIN( DateDiff( NOW(), str_to_date(idx_common.list_date,'%m/%d/%Y') ))) AS listage_min,
MAX( DateDiff( NOW(), str_to_date(idx_common.list_date,'%m/%d/%Y') ))) AS listage_max
```

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date contains the answer you seek.

However - please consider using real DATETIME columns instead of strings in your database, if at all possible.

Comment: Fair enough - been in that situation myself... that's why I added the if at all possible.. sometimes you just gotta work with the data you've got. Just use the str_to_date function I linked to and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

use java or c# or something to split the string of the date by the / and reorder the date into the format expected by mysql before you run the mysql query.